# NullPointerException при попытке инициализировать LinearLayout android

Tags: java, android, null

`Всем доброго дня, я в замешательстве:
У меня есть PopupMenu и невидимый LinearLayout в activity_main
При клике на строку popupmenu в идеале этот LinearLayout должен становиться видимым, но я никак не могу его инициализировать, вылетает исключение:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.admin.voicedetecting3.MainActivity.showModify(MainActivity.java:153)
                                                                                   at com.example.admin.voicedetecting3.MainActivity$2.onMenuItemClick(MainActivity.java:108)
```

Вот мой метод popupmenu

```
 public void showPopupMenu(View v, final String by_mark) {
    Context wrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(cont, R.style.MyPopupMenu);
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(wrapper, v);
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
    popupMenu
        .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.delete:
                            OH oh= new OH(cont, "data",null,0);
                            SQLiteDatabase db = oh.getWritableDatabase();
                            try {
                                db.delete(OH.TABLE_NAME, OH.KEY_METRIC + "=" + by_mark, null);
                            }catch (SQLException se){

                            }




                            Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM " +OH.TABLE_NAME, null);
                            int countString = 0;
                            if(null != cursor)
                                if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
                                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                                    countString = cursor.getInt(0);
                                }
                            cursor.close();
                            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();


                            for(int i=1; i<countString; i++){
                                values.put(OH.KEY_ID, i);
                            }


                            db.insert(OH.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
                            fillRecycleView();

                            break;
                        case R.id.modify:
                            //ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ ПРОИСХОДИТ ИСКЛЮЧЕНИЕ
                            mdfbl=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.modifyable);
                            mdfbl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //КОНЕЦ
                            break;
                    }


                    return false;
                }
            });

    popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:id="@+id/modifyable">
      <include layout="@layout/modify_string"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

```
    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/detected_text"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/detected_text"
                />



            <Button
                android:layout_width="400dp"
                android:layout_height="400dp"
                android:id="@+id/detect"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/microphone"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/metric_fill"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:hint="@string/here_will_be_metrics_to_find"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rool_fill"
        android:ellipsize="start"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/this_is_an_example_how_to_add_rools"
        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/remove"
        android:id="@+id/delete_db"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/modifyable"
            >
            <include layout="@layout/modify_string"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        />


    </LinearLayout>
```

```
``@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Вот начало
    mdfbl=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.modifyable);
    metric_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.metric_fill);
    rool_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rool_fill);
    cont=getApplication();
    add_rool=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
    assert add_rool != null;
    add_rool.setOnClickListener(this);
    delete_rool=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delete_db);
    assert delete_rool != null;
    delete_rool.setOnClickListener(this);

    detect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.detect);
    assert detect != null;
    detect.setOnClickListener(this);
    detected_text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.detected_text);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
   fillRecycleView();

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте вынести строку `mdfbl=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.modifyable);` сразу после `setContentView(...)`.

Comment: уже пробовал, не робит

Comment: а если быть точнее, то эта строка как раз работает, но тогда nullPointerException происходит на смене видимости

Comment: Стоит, наверное, еще уточнить, что исключение происходит именно при вызове метода видимости из popupmenu методп

Comment: @KostyaM где это вызывается? Activity/Fragment? xml файл для них?

Comment: Это обычный Activity AppCompact который, если я вас правильно понял?

Comment: Добавьте к описанию xml этой активити. а то так непонятно

Comment: там много всего, ну если сможете найти ))

Comment: как бы попонятнее, чтоб вам легче было искать

Comment: я изменил вопрос, добавил

Comment: как называется этот xml и напишите как вы вызваете setContentView() у активити?. Я сделал тестовый пример у себя с вашим кодом и у меня все работает

Comment: Скажу так, если я работаю с этим layout из onCreate(), то все прекрасно, проблема возникает именно при рботе с выше изложенным методом

Answer (score 1):

Ваш пример (удалил кое-что), но работающий.
Активити

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout mdfbl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);
    final Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testButton);
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showPopupMenu(testButton);
        }
    });
}

public void showPopupMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.modify);
    popupMenu
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.modify:
                            mdfbl= (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.modifyable);
                            mdfbl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
    popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {
        }
    });
    popupMenu.show();
}}
```

Меню xml file name modify.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/modify"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/></menu>
```

Файл для активити activity_scrolling.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:clipChildren="false">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/modifyable"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#00ff00"/>

<Button
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/testButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#00ff00"/></FrameLayout>
```

Работает так https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_FpaJARaBB2YjZRNTBuQjhNX1E/view?usp=sharing 
Надеюсь это вам поможет найти ошибку.

Comment: пффффффффф, все так же

Comment: тогда вот еще уточнение

Comment: PopupMenu у меня выпадает при нажатии на элемент RecyсlerView и из класса предоставляющего этот RecyсlerView и вызывается метод show_popup_menu, возможно что то из-за этого

Comment: попробуйте вызвать его из этой же активити по нажатию на кнопку, будет работать?

Comment: да, будет работать)